# How to know which Firefox profile has been opened?

Tags: firefox

Is there any way to know which Firefox profile has been opened?

Suppose I have opened my Firefox instance. How can I know which Firefox profile is in use? (Suppose I have five Firefox profiles.)

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few files in the profile folder are more-or-less continuously updated while Firefox is open. So look for the profile folder with the newest files, and that should tell you which one is currently (or most recently) open.

In Windows 7, the profile folders are under `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to menu Help, click Troubleshooting Information, then click the `Show Folder` button at the Application Basics section.

Comment: This works fine, just some of the entries have been renamed meanwhile.
The Help menu entry is now called `More Troubleshooting information`,
and entry in the Application Basics is called `Profile Folder`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Firefox extension that lets you know just that.

It can be found [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/show-profile/?src=search)

note: i never used it, nor own it.

Answer (score 1):

Put `about:profiles` in address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will open special page with information about all profiles. [about:profiles screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yCgM.jpg). There you can view path to profiles, their names, create, delete, or do whatever useful action you can do with them.

This feature present in Firefox since 46 version.

Answer (score 0):

Another add-on that provides this functionality is [ProfileSwitcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/profileswitcher/), which, as its name suggests, also allows you to switch between profiles at the click of a dropdown. The current profile can be added to toolbars, etc. by right-clicking and choosing "Customize".